# Word - Page break: Continue text from page 1 on page 3

Tags: microsoft-word

I have the following problem: 
I have a document that has "many" pages. At some point, there is a page that contains: a full-page image or table. So the reduced version of what I want looks like

```
Page 1: Text

Page 2: Image/Table (this page might be in landscape)

Page 3: Text (continuing the text from Page 1).
```

How can I make Word automatically continue the text on Page 3 when I write (one additional line) on Page 1. What happens in my case is

```
Page 1: Text 

Page 2: one line 

Page 3: Image/Table (this page might be in landscape)

Page 4: Text
```

I am using Word for Office 365 MSO.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You probably have your picture "wrapping style"set to "in line with text", try to set it to "top and bottom"

[image]

More information: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/wrap-text-around-a-picture-in-word-bdbbe1fe-c089-4b5c-b85c-43997da64a12

Comment: Thanks a lot. But, no, unfortunately, this does not really help! Also when one page 2 is in landscape, this does not work...

Comment: "Also when one page 2 is in landscape, this does not work" - that means you have section breaks between the pages. Currently there is no solution to continue text across sections, you need to start manually on page 3